# propagate tornado iostream error/exception

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I'm currently writing a async tcp-forwarder for the hl7-protocol in tornado (essentially, messages are forwarded to another endpoint and back, while the sockets stay open).

Currently, the implementation is an instance of TCPServer, whose channels connect to another destination. So there are for sockets, s1 <--> s2 and s3 <--> s4, where s1 is the client, s2 is the socket accepted by TCPServer instance, s3 is the forwarder and s4 the actual endpoint we want to talk to.

Now assume that s4 issues an error and closes the channel. In the IOStream's socket object s3 the error is set to e.g. ECONNREFUSED.

How can I propagate this error to tell the client s1 what happened. Essentially, I would like to close socket s2 with an error (or any other error) to indicate what happend. It doesn't have to be a ECONNREFUSED, since this one is risen while a channel is set up and this has happend already between s1 and s2.

thanks
markus